# amcharts and customBullet

Tags: javascript, c#, amcharts

I need to change my customBullet. Need change color and font-size, can you help me?
My code below:

```
"dataProvider": [{
                //"title": "Website visits",
                "year": 2009,
                "income": 23.5,
                "expenses": 18.1,
                "customDescription": "money$$$",                
            }],
    ..............
    "graphs": [{
                "labelText": "[[customDescription]]",
                ....
            },
    ....
```

What property can set size and color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no bullet font size but the [balloon settings](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmBalloon) can be changed in general

```
AmCharts.makeChart("..",{
    "balloon": {
        "adjustBorderColor": true,
        "color": "#000000",
        "cornerRadius": 5,
        "fillColor": "#FFFFFF"
    }
});
```

if you were talking about the bullet itself lookup the [graph documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bullet) and search for "bullet" it shows you all poissibilities